# Expansion of $1-\frac{1}{p}$

Tags: calculus, analysis

My professor wrote the following identity in our analysis class:
$$
1-1/p=\exp(-1/p+O(1/p^2))
$$
where $O(h(x))$ means a function $f(x)$ that satisfies $|f(x)|\leq C h(x)$ for some constant $C$.
With that being said, can somebody explain the intuition behind this expansion of $1-1/p$?

Comment: Note that $\exp(x)\approx 1+x$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is derived from the expansion of

> $$\log(1-x) = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty {x^n\over n}$$

by setting $x = {1\over p}$ and applying the exponential function to both sides.

Comment: You don't need the whole Maclaurin series, just the tangent-line approximation.